# Build Z3 for StarExec

Tags: z3

In the forthcoming [Termination Competition](http://termination-portal.org/wiki/Termination_Competition_2015), which is run on [StarExec](https://www.starexec.org), we want to use Z3 as SMT solver in our tool Ultimate Buchi Automizer.

First, I used the Z3 executable from my computer. On **StarExec** the execution failed. That's the error message:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

Next, I rebuild Z3 but adding this line:

```
LINK_FLAGS=-static
to build/config.mk.
```

in order to obtain a statically linked executable. It works fine on my computer, but on **StarExec** I get the following error message:

```
49541 Illegal instruction     (core dumped)
```

How can I build Z3 in order to run it on StarExec?

I seems that the problem is related to compiler optimizations for CPUs. When I build Z3 on an older machine it also works on StarExec.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the mk_make.py script command line parameters to specify static linking